# Why does live camera capture control with Xamarin Forms on iOS freeze?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I downloaded the source for [Xamarin Moments](https://xamarin.com/prebuilt/moments) from GitHub and now I'm trying to convert the [`CameraPage` renderer](https://github.com/pierceboggan/Moments/blob/master/Moments%20-%20CSharp/Moments.iOS/Pages/CameraPage.cs) from `Page` to a `ContentView`

Then I refactored the code to make it a `ContentView` renderer. Most of the actual setup of the live preview and image capture comes from the Moments app with some refactoring where needed/preferred.

The live preview shows up but when I press the button to take the picture the app freezes without an exception, **not even in Xcode's console view.**

```cs
//this is how it's called: 
btnTakePicture.Clicked += (s,e)=> { GetCameraImage().Wait(); };

// this method freezes
public async Task<byte[]> GetCameraImage()
{
    byte[] imageBuffer = null;

    if (captureDeviceInput != null)
    { 
        var videoConnection = stillImageOutput.ConnectionFromMediaType(AVMediaType.Video);
        Console.WriteLine("[HASFIQWRPPOA] This message shows up");

// this is where the app freezes, even though the live preview still moves.
        var sampleBuffer = await stillImageOutput.CaptureStillImageTaskAsync(videoConnection);
        Console.WriteLine("[CLKJFADSFQXW] THIS DOESN'T SHOW UP");

        // var jpegImageAsBytes = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.JpegStillToNSData (sampleBuffer).ToArray ();
        var jpegImageAsNsData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.JpegStillToNSData(sampleBuffer);
        Console.WriteLine("[ROIAJDGNQWTG]");
        // var image = new UIImage (jpegImageAsNsData);
        // var image2 = new UIImage (image.CGImage, image.CurrentScale, UIImageOrientation.UpMirrored);
        // var data = image2.AsJPEG ().ToArray ();
        imageBuffer = jpegImageAsNsData.ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine("[FIOUJGAIDGUQ] Image buffer: "+imageBuffer.Length);
    } 

    if (imageBuffer != null && imageBuffer.Length > 100)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBuffer))
        {
            var uiimg = UIImage.LoadFromData(NSData.FromStream(ms)); 
            this.Add(new UIImageView(uiimg)); 
        }
    }

    return imageBuffer;
}
```

Here is how I set the live preview

```cs
// This method runs fine and the camera preview is started as expected
    public void SetupLiveCameraStream()
    {
        try
        {   
// add a UIView to the renderer
            liveCameraStream = new UIView()
            { 
                Frame = new CGRect(0f, 0f, Element.Width, Element.Height),  
            };   

            this.Add(liveCameraStream);  
// find a camera
            var captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.DefaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Video);

            if (captureDevice != null)
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("[ZKSDJGWEHSY] Capture device found"); // not the case on simulator

                captureSession = new AVCaptureSession(); 

                videoPreviewLayer = new AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(captureSession)
                {
                    Frame = liveCameraStream.Bounds
                };

                liveCameraStream.Layer.AddSublayer(videoPreviewLayer);

                ConfigureCameraForDevice(captureDevice);

                captureDeviceInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.FromDevice(captureDevice);

                var dictionary = new NSMutableDictionary();
                dictionary[AVVideo.CodecKey] = new NSNumber((int)AVVideoCodec.JPEG);
                stillImageOutput = new AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
                {
                    OutputSettings = new NSDictionary()
                };

                captureSession.AddInput(captureDeviceInput);
                captureSession.AddOutput(stillImageOutput);
                captureSession.StartRunning();
                Console.WriteLine("[OIGAJGUWRJHWY] Camera session started"); 
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[OASDFUJGOR] Could not find a camera device");
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[QWKRIFQEAHJF] ERROR:" + x);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have a content view and there are two buttons and on button click i have to take the image and show as a preview ,how i can do that ????

Comment: @SayedAzharuddin please post another question if this post doesn't help. Also note that `btnTakePicture.Clicked +=...` code above. You can convert the `byte[]`: `var strm = new MemoryStream(buffer);  var imgsrc = ImageSource.FromStream(strm);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue, and it turned out I was deadlocking because of a combination of using `async`/`await` with `Task.Result`. At a guess you could be experiencing something similar with your usage of `Task.Wait()`.

The two sections of code:

```
btnTakePicture.Clicked += await (s,e) => { GetCameraImage().Wait(); };
```

And:

```
var sampleBuffer = await stillImageOutput.CaptureStillImageTaskAsync(videoConnection);
```

Comment: so the answer is to make my button.Clicked an async method?

Comment: Yes, try something like: `btnTakePicture.Clicked += async (s,e) => { await GetCameraImage(); };`